Difficulty Grasping Shell Method; Volumes of Revolution Around Lines Other than the $X$ or $Y$ Axes
MyMathLab Problem, Revolution About Different Axes
Hello, very new to the site and Stack Exchange in general. Reviewing and doing homework in preparation for our first Calculus II exam, and I'm having trouble understanding where I'm going wrong here in my process for solving volumes of revolution utilizing the shell method. In particular, questions where the rotation occurs about lines other than the $x$ or $y$ axes.
I've tried multiple ways to set up the problem / integral, but each time I keep getting the incorrect answer. To my understanding, for the question posted in my image, the setup should occur as such for a vertical rotation about $x = 7$ :
$$2π(7-x)(6x+7-x^2)$$
With an integration of lower bound $(a) = 0$, and an upper bound $(b) = 7. \ (7-x)$ being the shell radius, and $(6x+7-x^2)$ being the shell height. I've been trying to solve a ton of these kinds of problems, with axes of revolution besides standard $x$ and $y$, and keep coming up short. I have no idea where I'm going wrong, because I'm fairly certain I'm doing the integration right.
Can anyone provide some insight? Please and thank you. Been hitting a wall here.

Welcome to MSE! Since you're new, I wanted to give you some tips on how to best make use of the site. It would be easier for others to answer your question if it were self-contained, i.e. if you included the question you're trying to solve instead of making people click on a image link. It's very good that you've included some mathjax formatting, and it's good that you included your idea. I'll note that you can format an integral from $a$ to $b$ by typing $\int_a^b f(x) dx$, which renders as $\int_a^b f(x) dx.$

I suggest that you draw a picture. The bounds of integration shouldn't be from $0$ to $7$, since the parabola $x^2$ doesn't intersect the line $6x + 7$ at $0$. The correct bounds of integration are from $-1$ to $7$. And that gives the correct answer.

Wow, okay. Cannot believe I missed that. I figured it had to be something simple. I will be more careful when graphing these equations on the calculator from now on, and use actual paper to graph out the problems as well. Thank you so much!!

If possible it's probably best to transform the shape so it's centered around one of the axes, calculate the volume, then transform it back to its original position.

To ensure that you truly know how to solve cylindrical shell volume questions, I suggest that you try to solve the worked out examples from related textbooks in a good library WITHOUT looking at their solutions until after you have completed the question.
As you do more and more questions successfully from a variety of textbooks, your skill, speed and confidence will increase.
This technique is applicable to many types of Math problems or even other subjects where you have access to textbooks with lots of worked out examples.
Good luck!

The first thing to do in one of these questions is to make sure you know what region is being rotated about whatever axis of rotation is requested.
A good way to start is to completely graph every curve and line that you're given as a boundary of the region, at least far enough so that you can find all of the intersections that might be "corners" of the region.
It's also good to plot the axis of rotation on the same graph.
You have left out part of the region in the setup of your integral. I'll let you try to figure out what the missing part is.
